# Wrong button image on iPad device but not in the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ipad, retina-display

I am updating my universal app and naming my image files as follows:

```
buttonHelp.png
buttonHelp@2x.png
buttonHelp~iPad.png
buttonHelp@2x~iPad.png
```

This works fine on the simulator, but on my device (classic iPad running iOS 5.1) only buttonHelp.png shows up! (I have also tried "ipad" instead of "iPad").

Any suggestions?

Comment: If simulator works well and device does not, then it usually is a matter of case-sensitivity - that is, your file actually uses different letter cases than your given image names. You may also try to do a clean build as Xcode tends to cache image files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filenames are case sensitive, and must use lowercase ~ipad and @2x~ipad

```
buttonHelp.png
buttonHelp@2x.png
buttonHelp~ipad.png
buttonHelp@2x~ipad.png
```

Double check that XCode is actually transferring the files by removing the installed version from your device, doing a clean build, and reinstalling.

Also check each of the files are in listed in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' section of your 'Build Phases' in your project settings.

Reference:

> Standard: <ImageName><device_modifier>.<filename_extension>
>
> High resolution: <ImageName>**@2x<device_modifier>**.<filename_extension>

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html

Comment: Thanks, I think "ipad" in lower case solves the problem. (I tried that before but this time I was more successful).

Comment: @Dave - thanks...changing to lower case p in ipad fixed the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that buttonHelp@2x~iPad.png should be buttonHelp~iPad@2x.png.

The compiler does the trick where it sources all images with the @2x at the **end of the file name** for the retina display. If that image isn't found, though, it should default to the non-retina version, though.

Have you tried getting rid of the tilde in the filename?